# Variable accessed by multiple methods in the controller, and in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, model-view-controller

I have a controller Abc, and a variable `ev` filled with values in method1. I need to access the contents of this variable in the `method1` view, so I defined a helper_method for that. Now I also have a second `method2` (called when the form in `method1` is submitted) which needs to use **exactly** what was stored in `@ev` in `method1`, but for some reason, `@ev` is `nil` at the beginning of `method2`, although it works perfectly fine on the view. Why is the state of `@ev` not preserved? What can I do to fix this? (If there are multiple possible ways, i.e. a "hack" one and a proper solution, I'd love to hear them both.)

```
class AbcController < ApplicationController
    helper_method :ev

    def method1
        @ev = "gets dynamically filled here"
    end

    def method2
        @ev.first.nil?
    end

    private
       def ev
           @ev ||= []
       end
end
```

And the method1-view containing the form which directs to method2:

```
<%= form_tag(controller: :abcs, action: :method2)  do%>

    <% ev.each do |g| %>
        <%= radio_button_tag(:evn, "#{g.first.id}") %>
        <%= g.first.name %><br>
    <% end %>
    <%= submit_tag %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: How did you call method2? In separate requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instance variables set in a controller action are available to the whole controller and the view - you don't need the helper_method or the private method for that.

This is a highly abstract example, but I would say that if `@ev` is nil, `method2` probably gets called before `method1` has had a chance to set it.

Comment: Sorry for being so abstract. I would consider it rather unlikely that method2 is called afterwards, since ev is rendered in the form - where it is obviously set, works correctly; and method2 is called upon submitting the form. I added part of the view to the question.

Comment: Wait, those are two different requests! In request 1, you render the form through method 1 - `@ev` is set. Then you POST to method2 in a second request - `@ev` is not set anymore, since the state of your controller is not preserved between requests.

Comment: Okay, seems clear to me. Would I get around this by saying `@@ev` ?

Comment: I would strongly advise against it. If you're running your app in a multithreaded environment, `@@ev` would be shared between multiple requests at the same time. This leads to very ugly bugs. Were does the content of `@ev` come from? Can you reload it from somewhere for the POST to method2? Put it in the session? Pass it as a form parameter?

Comment: Just to close this: I finally went for passing (the most important parts of) the contents as parameters through hidden input fields. Thanks again for clearing the HTTP/stateless/request thing for me in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Its because the controller object gets created when method2 is called on the controller. Principle: Each time a URL (in this case form does that) is submitted to the browser, a new controller object is created and the corresponding method is called on that.